# Dataframe treat data with different decimal houses

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal, continuous

I have this column in my dataset where the values are not consistent.

You can either find values with just one decimal house or four decimal values.
I need this columns to calculate some means.
How can I treat this column?

[image]

Comment: Which column are you referring? The one with the comma?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how many decimal places each number has, the .mean() function is going to work on all of those columns no problem. `mean_df = df.mean(axis=0, skipna=True)` will work no problem and calculate average for each column, assuming that df is the dataframe you provided in the picture :)

Comment: what you meant by 'find values'? what is the outcome you're expecting. please add what you have tried so far along with the data as text, and not image

Comment: @RichardKraus I have some values like this: 159,927,446. I'll it work?

Comment: @P.Brito ofc, it should work, try it out. Or edit your question to include some testing data, if you have it in csv just copy a couple of lines :)